# Getting null values when reading json using ConfigurationBuilder in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a simple console application in which I just reading items from a `configuration.json` file. I am using `IConfigurationRoot` interface to save the JSON configuration object.

here is my configuration.json file:

```json
{
  "Configuration": {
    "one": "one",
    "two": "two",
    "three": "three"
  }
}
```

My code:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    public Program()
    {
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("configuration.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).Build();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        string one = p.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Configuration:one");
        string two = p.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Configuration:two");
        string three = p.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Configuration:three");
        Console.WritLine(one);
        Console.WritLine(two);
        Console.WritLine(three);
 
    }
}
```

I am getting this when I am printing the values.

I tried GetSection as well and got null in it as well.

Updated:

The issue is file is not found but the file exists in the folder

[image: Exception Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have `configuration.json` file in correct location? Do you get exception if you set `optional: false`?

Comment: Yes by making it optional: false I am getting an exception. I added a screenshot in the updated question

Comment: See if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) helps.

Comment: Post the exception text as *text* in the question itself, not as an unreadable screenshot. The exception itself is telling you the file *doesn't* exist. You're loading the file using a relative path. That's relative to the executable, not the project folder. Change the file's properties to `Content` and make sure the `Copy to output directory` isn't None

Comment: PS: .NET Core 3.1 is reaching [End Of Life](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) in December 13, 2022. The current Long Term Support version is .NET 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `configuration.json` file in wrong location.

From exception the file should exist in `C:\Users\samee\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` folder.

You have several options here:

1. If file is included in solution then you can set in file properties `Build action` to `Content` and `Copy to output directory` to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`. This option is preferred - see why in options below.
2. Move `configuration.json` file there manually - but if you change configuration to `Release` then you should also manually move the file there.
3. Pass full (absolute) file path to `AddJsonFile()` method - but if you use some repository like Git on every PC you'll have different absolute path.

Answer (score -1):

First, .NET Core 3.1 [reaches End of Life in December 13, 2022](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). That's one month from now. The current Long-Term-Support version is .NET 6, supported until November 2024.

The exception says that the file can't be found. You're using a relative path to load it. The path is relative to the executable's path, not the project path. When debugging, the executable is in `bin\Debug\net...`.

To make .NET copy the file to the output folder automatically change its properties to `Content`. This ensures that the file is copied both to the output *and* the publish folder. Make sure the `Copy to Output Directory` action is set to `Copy Always` or `Copy Newer`.